# Issues with 4.13.0-25 and 17.10 on a VM

Tags: 17.10

4.13.0-25-generic won't boot on my VMs running 17.10. I had to manually go in and select the 4.13.0-16-generic kernal.

Curiously 4.13.0-25-generic is working on my other cloud server just fine (as far as I can tell).

For me, only VMs running 17.10 are affected: VMs running 16.x are unaffected after the meltdown patching (with the 4.4.0-109-generic kernal).

Anyone know when this will be fixed? Right now my VM server needs to have the 17.10 VMs manually booted to the previous kernal thereby making my recovery script ineffective should I loose power.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

The 4.13.0-25 on 17.10 and 4.4.0-109 on 16.04 updates for Meltdown affect how the Linux kernal operates in a virtual environment. This is important because anyone running a large number of Linux servers is doing it on ESXI and VBox VM environments. My bare metal cloud servers seem unaffected and gladly took the changes with no complaint. The VMs were another story..

For those who are using Oracle VirtualBox there was a change in how 'Enable VT-x/AMD-V' and 'Enable Nested Paging' work in response to how the Meltdown changes in the released Linux kernal (with respect how VBox runs them). Modifying the values do not have any affect - the only resolution is upgrade 5.0.x to a version that 're-connects' this functionality.

I used VB 5.0.x and found that VirtualBox 5.2.x will totally work with the newest Meltdown Ubuntu kernels. So my fix was the following:

(1) Stop current VBox activities:

```
Issued these commands and kill-9'd everything I could:

  ps aux | grep vbox
  ps aux | grep virtualbox
```

(2) Install the 5.2.x version of VirtualBox on my Ubuntu 17.10 server:

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.2

  and don't forget: sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

(3) Rebooted server and crossed fingers hoping that I did not bring down a dozen PROD VMs (and I didn't).

My administrative version of phpVirtualBox runs fine with 5.2 and all of my VMs came up with the Meltdown kernal updates (and host server is 16.04LTS and has the 4.4.0-109 kernal).

I am Meltdown patched, and have an updated Oracle VBox headless to v5.2 and my startup scripts I wrote worked unaffected.

I hope this helps someone else in my situation. Here is some more details on this known issue: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=86185

The VBox logs on my system showed this too: emR3Debug: rc=VERR_PGM_INVALID_CR3_ADDR

tags: Linux kernal updates for meltdown, meltdown changes affect how updated kernels on VMs run, Linux kernal 13.0.25, Linux kernal 4.4.0-109